# Syntax error: Unexpected "score: at "execute if >>score<< Seconds Timer matches 60

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a digital clock using the scoreboard commands and command blocks, when I try doing this and have followed steps correctly it says `Syntax error: Unexpected "score: at "execute if >>score<< Seconds Timer matches 60..` in the previous output area and I can't find a solution anywhere. When I originally tried it on a tester world, it worked so I went over to do it on the world it was necessary for and it didn't work, when I rejoined my tester world and re-did the commands exactly as I did before, it didn't work and said the same Syntax Error. I have tried using `scoreboard players test Seconds Timer 60` as a substitute but this too has not worked for me.

Comment: Is your testworld where the command worked in the same version like you other world?
Sometimes commands are changed from one version to another.

Maybe you could pots your command, that so people could better help you.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments are wrong. You used the Java arguments not the bedrock ones. These are the bedrock arguments:

```
execute <origin: target> <position: x y z> <command: command>
```

For the Java arguments that you used visit: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute

Notice: Bedrock arguments are the same as Java

Comment: You said that "The arguments are wrong." but you also said "Bedrock arguments are the same as Java". These can't both be true.